# Convert from LocalTime to TimeSpan

Tags: sql-server, automapper, nodatime, localtime, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am using NodaTime and Entity Framework Core in my application.  I am using AutoMapper to convert from my models (which use LocalTime) to my entities (which use Timespan which is mapped to Time in Sql Server).  I am doing it this way to avoid the pitfalls of EF ValueConversions.

When going from entities to models (i.e. Timespan to LocalTime), I found the "official" way of doing it (https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/148):

```
LocalTime.FromTicksSinceMidnight(timespan.Ticks)
```

But, going from models to entities (i.e. LocalTime to Timespan), I am not sure what the best way is. Dates and times seem too tricky to just grab the hours, minutes, etc like:

```
new TimeSpan(localTime.Hour, localTime.Minute, localTime.Second, localTime.Second, localTime.Millisecond)
```

Should I utilize ticks like when going from LocalTime to Timespan?

```
TimeSpan.FromTicks(localTime.TickOfSecond)
```

Comment: I've edited the title as it sounds like you've got TimeSpan to LocalTime sorted, and it's the other direction which is causing you problems. Feel free to edit it back if I've got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: You are correct on your title edit, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting from `LocalTime` to `TimeSpan`, you can indeed use ticks - but you want `TickOfDay`:

```cs
TimeSpan timeSinceMidnight = TimeSpan.FromTicks(localTime.TickOfDay);
```

Comment: When I read "Gets the tick of this local time within the second", I thought that was taking seconds into account being more accurate.  But, after re-reading the ranges, using TickOfDay makes more sense. Thanks!